# MessageBox equivalent in Android?

Tags: android

What would it be?  (It would have an "[OK]" button on it too.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).

Subclasses for it exist that may be more/less appropriate for you.  Take a look specifically at the [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) class.  There is also an [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) sub-class that will assist in creating an `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

You case use [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) class.

Comment: Awesome!  I like Toast, and even am using that in lieu of the Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple use of AlertDialog:

```
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(theContext).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("End Game?");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to end the game?");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {   
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {
                finish();                   
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {   
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {
                                }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
```

Thought I'd add what I did after coming across this page, as it would have been useful for me to see !! - Hope this helps the next guy or gal :-)